# Why is NSObject ini event triggered 2 times?

Tags: cocoa

I have an NSObject

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

@interface MyObj1 : NSObject<NSApplicationDelegate> {

}



@end

//
//  MyObj1.m


#import "MyObj1.h"


@implementation MyObj1


-(id)init;
{
    //I set the breakpoint here

}

@end
```

I set the breakpoint as above, but I found that it always triggers ini event 2 times

I do not know if it is normal or anything wrong?

Welcome any comment

Comment: Well, are you creating two instances of `MyObj1`?

Comment: Also, `-init` is not an event — it’s a method. In particular, it’s an initialiser method that’s used to put the object in a valid state.

Comment: Since this is your application delegate, I'd bet there's already one in your .xib. Are you also creating one in code? That would make a total of two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an easy way to find out: Just look at the stack trace in the debugger, and you will see how both objects are created. There are certainly two of them, maybe one within a nib and one programmatically. Typically, you never instantiate your app delegate yourself directly.